# Greens function representation of nonlinear Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, greens-function, greens-theorem, linear-pde

Let $L$ be an operator and suppose the Green's function exists. That is there exist a function $G$ such that $LG=\delta$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.
If $L$ is linear, one can represent the solution $u$ of the Poisson equation $Lu=f$ by $u(x)=\int_{\Omega}G(x,y)f(y)dy$ as discussed in the following link :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function

My question is can we get the same representation of $u$ if $L$ becomes nonlinear?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $G$ such that $LG=\delta$, with boundary condition $G=0$, and define
$$
u(x)=\int_\Omega G(x,y)f(y)dy.
$$

Then apply the operator $L$ to $u$ and get:
$$
Lu(x)=L \int_\Omega G(x,y)f(y)dy.
$$
If its true that $L \int_\Omega G(x,y)f(y)dy = \int_\Omega LG(x,y)f(y)dy,$ then
$$
Lu(x)=\int_\Omega \delta(x,y)f(y)dy=f(x)
$$
and $u$ solves the equation $Lu=f$ in $\Omega$.
The question now is when it is possible to bring the operator $L$ inside the integral. If the operator is linear it can be easily done. If $L$ is nonlinear, it cannot be done in many cases.

Comment: Thank you very much.